# Is console.writeline thread safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, console, thread-safety, console.writeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling Console.WriteLine from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079980/calling-console-writeline-from-multiple-threads)

Just want to know if multiple threads call `Console.WriteLine`, will it cause a deadlock?

Comment: Deadlocks would be much less likely than race conditions (assuming that it's *not* thread-safe)

Comment: It's more likIf it isn't threadsafe.ely to produce output like this.

Answer (score 71):

It's safe! From the [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console):

> **Console I/O Streams**
>
> [...]
>
> I/O operations using these streams are synchronized, which means multiple threads can read from, or write to, the streams.