# Text colour conundrem

Tags: vb.net

How do I change the "text that is displayed to the screen when the programme is run" colour in visual basic?

My problem is that I want the WriteLine to come up in a different colour text than other parts of the code.

```
If Opt2 = 2 Then 
   Console.WriteLine("Hard mode selected. Good luck, and may the odds be ever in your favour.")
   Console.ReadLine()
   Opt3 = 2
End If
```

If anyone knows how to do this please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write to the console in colour in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net)