# C# foreground color of portion of a stringbuilder object

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am working on a C# console project in Visual Studio, and I want to change the color of a portion of a `StringBuilder` object. I can't write that part of the code to the console immediately with a `WriteLine` because it's part of a larger paragraph. Therefore, the solution presented in [Is it possible to write to the console in colour in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net) (using `WriteLine` statements between `ConsoleColor.Cyan` statements) is not applicable.

This is my current method:

```
internal void ShowItems(StringBuilder builder, Player player)
{
    foreach (Item item in Program.items.Values)
    {
        if (item.CurrentLocation == player.CurrentLocation.Name && item.CurrentLocation == item.InitialLocation)
        {
            builder.Append(item.InitialText);
        }
        else if (item.CurrentLocation == player.CurrentLocation.Name && item.CurrentLocation != item.InitialLocation)
        {
            builder.Append($" You see the {item.DisplayName.ToUpper()} here.");
        }
    }
}
```

I want part of the `item.InitialText` to appear in another color, say magenta. This color is different than the rest of the text. I can split `item.InitialText`, into the strings I want, but how do I make one of those strings a different color?

I have looked in several resources, but they all seem to be for rich text boxes or other graphical interfaces, not console output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net

Comment: A string doesn't have a colour (and neither does a SringBuilder), but you can print in colour at the time when you actually write to the console. You'll have to rig your own method of remembering which colour to print each stirng in. Maybe a custom class that contains a string and a `ConsoleColor`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I edited my original post. The reference to the other stackoverflow post does not apply.

Comment: It doesn't look edited to me..

Comment: @Blorgbeard Better?

Comment: Please don't include answers in your question. Even if the question is closed. In any case, it looks like your solution is using the same idea as the closed duplicate (writing a colour to the *console*, not into a string builder (which people have already mentioned is impossible)). This question should stay as a duplicate, as it's really asking how to print colour to the console.