# Setting background and foreground colors of Console App?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set the background and foreground colors of my console application. But no matter what I try, the colors do not differ from the default black & white.
This is the beginning of my Main method. I've tried with and without Console.Clear()

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Clear();
```

I've checked MSDN and searched SO already, and the above example seems to work for everybody else. Any advice?

Comment: Have you print something yet in the console to verifyif it is working? Because the code you posted is not showing it.

Comment: This is the only code? Just two of these lines?

Comment: No, there is more - the next line just writes to the console:

Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Create-A-Menu app!");

But I've also tried setting the background color with no success

Comment: That's the way to do it. Maybe you're using a different commandline shell? Try explicitly running cmd.exe, navigating to you app and running it via that commandline.

Comment: Try running visual studio as administrator.

Comment: Interesting - opening the project in visual studio as an administrator worked. Thanks @Berkay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write to the console in colour in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Clear();
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("Red background and white letters");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```