# c# Console.WriteLine() with color text is massing the output

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to show a warning to the user by the following code. But it is massing the output text.

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine($"The selected row {selection} is not found in the database.");
Console.ResetColor();
Console.ReadLine();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

The display looks as follows:-
[image]

I only want to make coloring of the text **"The selected row  is not found in the database."**. Nothing extra. Otherwise it looks ugly. How to do it?

Comment: Maybe use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine` ?

Comment: I think you find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net

Comment: It is caused by the console window scrolling, the new empty line revealed by the scroll is painted with the selected background color.  Consider using Write() instead of WriteLine().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the carriage return and new line draws the background color for these lines. Simply use `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
// only write without new line
Console.Write($"The selected row {selection} is not found in the database.");
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine(); // if necessary
Console.ReadLine();
Environment.Exit(0);
```