# In a C# console app, can you make one part of a message one color, and a different part another color?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, console.writeline

I want to print to the console a message with multiple colors.

For example:
`(red) error: (white) command not found`

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743260/is-it-possible-to-write-to-the-console-in-colour-in-net

Comment: use Console.ForegroundColor

Comment: You can use ANSI color codes as well: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-ansi-color-codes-in-net-console-apps/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Console.Write()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-5.0) to continue on the same line with different colors.

Code goes like this -

```
var originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write("error: ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.Write("command not found");
Console.ForegroundColor = originalColor;
```

Output -
[image]

Comment: Would using [this](https://github.com/silkfire/Pastel) be more or less efficient? I found it a while after asking the question.

Comment: It will be efficient if you are considering your code writing efforts. Also, if your application is very small and not a large scale application, using a packaged library will only increase the load on your project. There is always a trade-off when we are talking about efficiency. A wise decision depends on what your application requirements are or how are they going to be extended in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write("Hello,");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine(" World!");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Console.ForegroundColor` property.
First, create a class representing a fragment of your string
See the example below:

```
public string StringFragment { get; set; }

public ConsoleColor StringFragmentColor { get; set; }

public SpecialString(string wordFragment, ConsoleColor color)
{
    this.StringFragment = wordFragment;
    this.StringFragmentColor = color;
}

public void Display()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = this.StringFragmentColor;
    Console.Write(this.StringFragment);
}
```

And then, just call them in your code...

```
var wordFragment1 = new SpecialString("Hello", ConsoleColor.Green);
var wordFragment2 = new SpecialString(" World", ConsoleColor.Yellow);

wordFragment1.Display();
wordFragment2.Display();
```

Result:
[image]